# Difference between looping in the code when I try to loop and stop a function:

Tags: javascript

When I try to run the cycleimagesfunc() in javascript console, the first section of my code works, but then it doesn't work in the second section.  I'm trying to keep track of each key press so that a key press will trigger the function to run and display the next image.

```
<p id="demo8">first</p>

function cycleimagesfunc(){
    if(document.getElementById("demo8").innerHTML==="first"){
    document.getElementById("demo8").innerHTML ="third";
    console.log("0");
    return;
    }
    if(document.getElementById("demo8").innerHTML==="third"){
    document.getElementById("demo8").innerHTML ="fourth";
    console.log("1");
    return;
    }
    if(document.getElementById("demo8").innerHTML==="fourth"){
    document.getElementById("demo8").innerHTML ="fifth";
    console.log("2");
    return;
    }


    var cyclecount = 0;
    function cycleimagesfunc(){
    if(cyclecount = 0){
    console.log("0");
    cyclecount++;
    return;
    }
    if(cyclecount = 1){
    console.log("1");
    cyclecount++;
    return;
    }
    if(cyclecount = 2){
    console.log("2");
    cyclecount++;
    return;
    }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is with your use of single equals signs (`=`) instead of double equals signs (`==`) in your conditionals.

Comment: Thanks Obsidian Age

Comment: `if(cyclecount = 0)` is assignment.

Comment: note: your code indentation is absent :p

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your use of assignment operator (`=`) instead of the comparison operator (`==`) or (`===`) in your conditionals. This [**assigns**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) the `cyclecount` to the value instead of [**checking against**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) it. Note that use of a triple equals sign also guards against 'truthy' values by additionally checking the type.

You also shouldn't be running `return` in your function, as this will prevent any further function logic happening after the condition is met. You're presumably wanting to do something after the `cyclecount` increases!

The conditionals are fixed, and the returns are removed in the follow example:

```js
var cyclecount = 0;

function cycleimagesfunc() {
  if (cyclecount === 0) {
    console.log("0");
    cyclecount++;
  }
  if (cyclecount === 1) {
    console.log("1");
    cyclecount++;
  }
  if (cyclecount === 2) {
    console.log("2");
    cyclecount++;
  }
}

cycleimagesfunc();
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I recommend `===` to avoid truthy issues.

Comment: I agree, and I've updated the answer to recommend triple equals :)